# How to scroll up history in React chat page

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks, jquery-waypoints

**Trying to show a chat history with infinite reload similar to Skype or any popular chat app*

In a chat page. If my chat messages limit is 10 messages.

And the chat has 30.

It will show latest 10 when I load the chat.

When I scroll to the top I want to see the previous 10.

I tried this myself and the scroll position stays the same but the messages load in the view.

It should load to the top and hold the scroll position.

How can this be done?

Here's my page:
https://pastebin.com/36xZPG1W

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import produce from 'immer';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import { WithT } from 'i18next';
 
import * as ErrorHandler from 'components/ErrorHandler';
import useOnScreen from 'utils/useOnScreen';
 
import getLang from 'utils/getLang';
 
import Message from './Message';
const limit = 10;
const lang = getLang();
interface IMessagesProps extends WithT {
  messages: any;
  currentUserID: string;
  chatID: string;
  fetchMore: any;
  typingText: any;
  setSelectedMsg: any;
  removeMessage: any;
}
 
const Messages: React.FC<IMessagesProps> = ({
  messages,
  currentUserID,
  chatID,
  fetchMore,
  setSelectedMsg,
  removeMessage,
  t,
}) => {
  const elementRef = useRef(null);
  const isOnScreen = useOnScreen(elementRef);
  const topElementRef = useRef(null);
  const topIsOnScreen = useOnScreen(topElementRef);
 
  const isUserInside = useRef(true);
  const scroller = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const messagesEnd = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true);
 
  useEffect(() => {
    scrollToBottom();
  }, []);
 
  useEffect(() => {
    autoscroll();
  }, [messages]);
 
  //NOT WORKING
  const autoscroll = () => {
    // Visible height
    const visibleHeight = scroller.current.offsetHeight;
 
    // Height of messages container
    const containerHeight = scroller.current.scrollHeight;
 
    // How far have I scrolled?
    const scrollOffset = scroller.current.scrollTop + visibleHeight;
    // New message element
    const firstChild = scroller.current.firstElementChild;
    console.log(`visibleHeight`, visibleHeight);
    console.log(`containerHeight`, containerHeight);
    console.log(`scrollOffset`, scrollOffset);
    console.log(`firstChild`, firstChild.offsetHeight);
    console.log(`firstChild`, firstChild.scrollHeight);
    console.log(`firstChild`, firstChild);
    scroller.current.scrollTop = scrollOffset;
    // // Height of the new message
    // const newMessageStyles = getComputedStyle($newMessage)
    // const newMessageMargin = parseInt(newMessageStyles.marginBottom)
    // const newMessageHeight = $newMessage.offsetHeight + newMessageMargin
 
    // // Visible height
    // const visibleHeight = $messages.offsetHeight
 
    // // Height of messages container
    // const containerHeight = $messages.scrollHeight
 
    // // How far have I scrolled?
    // const scrollOffset = $messages.scrollTop + visibleHeight
 
    // if (containerHeight - newMessageHeight <= scrollOffset) {
    //     $messages.scrollTop = $messages.scrollHeight
    // }
  };
 
  const fetchDataForScrollUp = cursor => {
    ErrorHandler.setBreadcrumb('fetch more messages');
    if (!hasMore) {
      return;
    }
    fetchMore({
      variables: {
        chatID,
        limit,
        cursor,
      },
      updateQuery: (previousResult, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
        if (!fetchMoreResult?.getMessages || fetchMoreResult.getMessages.messages.length < limit) {
          setHasMore(false);
          return previousResult;
        }
        const newData = produce(previousResult, draftState => {
          draftState.getMessages.messages = [...previousResult.getMessages.messages, ...fetchMoreResult.getMessages.messages];
        });
 
        return newData;
      },
    });
  };
 
  if (messages?.length >= limit) {
    if (topIsOnScreen) {
      fetchDataForScrollUp(messages[messages.length - 1].id);
    }
  }
 
  if (isOnScreen) {
    isUserInside.current = true;
  } else {
    isUserInside.current = false;
  }
 
  const scrollToBottom = () => {
    if (messagesEnd.current) {
      messagesEnd.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    }
  };
 
  const groupBy = function (arr, criteria) {
    return arr.reduce(function (obj, item) {
      // Check if the criteria is a function to run on the item or a property of it
      const key = typeof criteria === 'function' ? criteria(item) : item[criteria];
 
      // If the key doesn't exist yet, create it
      if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
        obj[key] = [];
      }
 
      // Push the value to the object
      obj[key].push(item);
 
      // Return the object to the next item in the loop
      return obj;
    }, {});
  };
 
  const objectMap = object => {
    return Object.keys(object).reduce(function (result, key) {
      result.push({ date: key, messages: object[key] });
      return result;
    }, []);
  };
 
  const group = groupBy(messages, datum => dayjs(datum.createdAt).locale(lang).format('dddd, MMMM D, YYYY').toLocaleUpperCase());
  const messageElements = objectMap(group)
    .reverse()
    .map((item, index) => {
      const messageElements = item.messages
        .map(message => {
              return (
                <Message
                  key={uniqueKey}
                  message={message}
                  currentUserID={currentUserID}
                  lang={lang}
                  removeMessage={removeMessage}
                  t={t}
                  chatID={chatID}
                  setSelectedMsg={setSelectedMsg}
                />
              );
        })
        .reverse();
 
      return messageElements;
    })
    .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []);
 
  return (
    <div style={{ marginBottom: '25px' }}>
      <div ref={topElementRef} />
      <div
        style={{
          position: 'relative',
          display: 'flex',
          flexDirection: 'column',
          flexWrap: 'wrap',
          height: '100%',
          overflow: 'hidden',
        }}
        ref={scroller}
      >
        {messageElements}
        <div ref={elementRef} style={{ position: 'absolute', bottom: '5%' }} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
 
export default Messages;
```

Been stuck on this for 2 weeks lol. Any advice is helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) ? you can try after changing your `autoscroll` function like following

```
const autoscroll = () => {
   elementRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
  };
```

Comment: How would I know which element Scroll to?

Comment: Better yet, how/where do I maintain a ref to the top element when requesting new elements?

Comment: you can conditionally  add a div with ref in the between old message and new message, once you've reached at the new messages remove the added div and merge new messages into old messages, and clear the new messages values

Comment: Ah see there's the issue. When you merge new messages there's a rerender. The top div would simply reset to the top and it will not move from the top.

Comment: I was able to get close with this. But it still goes to the top. then rerenders and scrolls to position.

Its not the infinite scroll we'd expect

code:

  const autoscroll = () => {
    if( scroller.current?.children[limit+1]){
    scroller.current?.children[limit+1].scrollIntoView({behavior:"smooth"});}
  };

Comment: I was thinking, should I move the message getter to the same component as the waypoint for refetching?

Comment: not able to understand what you are trying to achieve, can you create a code sandbox to reproduce it and share url?

Comment: Thats would be pretty tough due to api needs.

If you've ever used Skype or any chat, you will notice if you want to go to message history. You have to scroll up so it fetches more msgs from your history. I want the exact same behavior.

Easier said then done. Here's an example of the functionality I want (no, the package didnt work for me)
https://codesandbox.io/s/6w5vx7yvwk?file=/src/index.js:766-778

Notice how the position doesnt change even when more info shows.

Comment: here is without `react-stay-scrolled` https://codesandbox.io/s/react-stay-scrolled-demo-forked-pgr10 if this is not working then  I am pretty sure there must issue with CSS , CSS style sometimes make things worse

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240848/discussion-between-notelonmusk-and-shubham-jha).